# Stop an audio play at an exact time

Tags: android, ios, audio

This question has a background for iOS but I am also asking in general.

I am developing an app that requires to start and stop playing an audio file at specific points on the timeline. Apart from finding out the duration of play by substracting the start-time from the stop-time and use the duration to set a separate timer to stop the audio play, is there a more effective way (an exact way) to control the stop?

Currently, my app, under the influence of its "weather" that the stop could be near or far, occasionally the stop will come too late and part of the audio after the specified stop point is played.

Now, I have examined audio editing program namely Audacity, by selecting a range on the timeline and hit play, Audacity starts and stops (at least to the naked ear or the feeble mind) precisely at the specified points. What is the underlying control mechanism and how it differs to iOS API?

Could iOS employ the same or similar mechanism? How about Android?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With Android u can start and stop the playback of a audiofile
at the axactly time in milliseconds also like in audacity.
In audacity the time is formated like this 00h00m00.000s.
The Time after the "." are the milliseconds , so u have to transfer both times to milliseconds.
Than u can seek to the start time and stop after the (start-stop)-time difference with a handler.

See here [Android: How to stop media (mp3) in playing when specific milliseconds come?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454452/android-how-to-stop-media-mp3-in-playing-when-specific-milliseconds-come)

but why u not cut the specific segment in audacity?

Comment: The reason why I don't cut out the segments is because the file is a recitation of a piece of literature and I do not just have 1 tier of segmentation, I have multi-tiers, that is, the book is broken down to the following: the entire book, the chapters, the sections (of chapter), the sentences (of section), the phrases (of sentence) and so on. Therefore it will be a lot more flexible to just describe such a hierarchy with an XML file.