# How to play an mp3 file between a range of milliseconds using android MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, audio, mp3, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am able to play an mp3 file using android's MediaPlayer object. But I would like to play between a range of milliseconds for example between 30000 ms to 40000 ms ( 10 seconds only ). How can I achieve this?

Currently the following code is what I have,

```
private MediaPlayer mPlayer;
public void play() {
    try {
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mp3_file);
        if (mPlayer != null) {
            int currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            if (currentPosition + 30000 <= mPlayer.getDuration()) {
                mPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition + 30000);
            } else {
                mPlayer.seekTo(mPlayer.getDuration());
            }
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method:

```
public int getCurrentPosition ()
```

to obtain the current time in milSeconds maybe inside a Handler that runs every 1000 milSeconds and tests to see:

```
if(mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() >= (mPlayer.getDuration + 40000));
```

Dont forget to [release](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()) the media file when you're done using it:

```
public void release();
mPlayer.release();
```

> Releases resources associated with this MediaPlayer object. It is
>   considered good practice to call this method when you're done using
>   the MediaPlayer. In particular, whenever an Activity of an application
>   is paused (its onPause() method is called), or stopped (its onStop()
>   method is called), this method should be invoked to release the
>   MediaPlayer object, unless the application has a special need to keep
>   the object around. In addition to unnecessary resources (such as
>   memory and instances of codecs) being held, failure to call this
>   method immediately if a MediaPlayer object is no longer needed may
>   also lead to continuous battery consumption for mobile devices, and
>   playback failure for other applications if no multiple instances of
>   the same codec are supported on a device. Even if multiple instances
>   of the same codec are supported, some performance degradation may be
>   expected when unnecessary multiple instances are used at the same
>   time.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use a Handler to time the stopping of the playback. Start the player and then use the Handler's `postDelayed` to schedule the execution of a `Runnable` that will stop the player. You should also start the player only after the initial seek completes. Something like this:

```
public class PlayWord extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener {
    Handler mHandler;
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    int mStartTime = 6889;
    int mEndTime = 7254;
    final Runnable mStopAction = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Playing...");
        setContentView(tv);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nicholas);
        mPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        mPlayer.seekTo(mStartTime);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mPlayer.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete (MediaPlayer mp) {
        mPlayer.start();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mStopAction, mEndTime - mStartTime);
    }
}
```

Note also that the `MediaPlayer.create` method you are using returns a MediaPlayer that has already been prepared and `prepare` should *not* be called again like you are doing in your code.on the screen. I also added a call to `release()` when the activity exits.

Also, if you want to update the UI when the seek completes, be aware that this method is usually called from a non-UI thread. You will have to use the handler to post any UI-related actions.

---

I'm copied this from: [Android: How to stop media (mp3) in playing when specific milliseconds come?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454452/android-how-to-stop-media-mp3-in-playing-when-specific-milliseconds-come?rq=1#answer-5666209)